# Another WPF/XAML Image in Button Event Trouble

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

I've put together the following XAML code to try and figure out why the Click event only fires when I click on the Image or TextBlock content inside the Button.  The area around these in the Button does not fire the click event:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBedApp.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Bisque">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Aqua">
            <Button x:Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Background="Olive">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image x:Name="img"
                                    Source="Images/MyImage.png"
                                    Width="100"
                                    Height="72"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="10">
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="Click Me" Foreground="White"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ooosh");
}
```

I've seen some samples on line using ContentPresenters, but I am after an explanation for this.  I am extremely new to XAML and just getting my feet wet.  I am using VS2013 and .NET 4.5 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the background property hasn't been set on your StackPanel. WPF will only register you having clicked something if there's actually something there being rendered, this is by design and allows you to do things like add geometry etc for unusually shaped buttons. If you really do want these areas of your button to be transparent then set the background property of the StackPanel in your ControlTemplate to "Transparent".

Answer (score 0):

IS there a reason why you want to set the `ControlTemplate`? If the main purpose is to get an image within the `Button`, or another other element for that matter, you can simply add it as a child:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Bisque">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Aqua">
        <Button x:Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Background="Olive">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image x:Name="img"
                                Source="Images/MyImage.png"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="72"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="10">
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="Click Me" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It was a Sacha Barber demo for the Panorama Panel I was experimenting with and just trying to do things and wonder why they weren't working as expected.  I am still getting to grips with the Control Template.  No doubts I have lots of questions on that but for now, setting the background to Transparent works for me below.  If I was writing from scratch I would have done it this way given my understanding on things and from other experiences.  I've not touched on ControlTemplates in WPF as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this..

Remove button's click event and use border's click event for showing messagebox.